# DP Coin Change Algorithm - Retrieve coin combinations from table

Tags: swift, dynamic-programming, coin-change

To find how many ways we have of making change for the amount `4` given the coins `[1,2,3]`, we can create a DP algorithm that produces the following table:

```
table[amount][coins.count]
        0 1 2 3 4
      -----------
(0) 1 | 1 1 1 1 1
(1) 2 | 1 1 2 2 3
(2) 3 | 1 1 2 3 4
```

The last position being our answer. The answer is `4` because we have the following combinations: `[1,1,1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,1]`.

My question is, is it possible to retrieve these combinations from the table I just generated? How?

For completeness, here's my algorithm

```
func coinChange(coins: [Int], amount: Int) -> Int {
    // int[amount+1][coins]
    var table = Array<Array<Int>>(repeating: Array<Int>(repeating: 0, count: coins.count), count: amount + 1)

    for i in 0..<coins.count {
        table[0][i] = 1
    }

    for i in 1...amount {
        for j in 0..<coins.count {

            //solutions that include coins[j]
            let x = i - coins[j] >= 0 ? table[i - coins[j]][j] : 0
            //solutions that don't include coins[j]
            let y = j >= 1 ? table[i][j-1] : 0

            table[i][j] = x + y
        }
    }
    return table[amount][coins.count - 1];
}
```

Thanks!

--

**Solution**

Here's an ugly function that retrieves the combinations, based on @Sayakiss 's explanation:

```
func getSolution(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> [[Int]] {
        if j < 0 || i < 0 {
            //not a solution
            return []
        }
        if i == 0 && j == 0 {
            //valid solution. return an empty array where the coins will be appended
            return [[]]
        }
        return getSolution(i - coins[j], j).map{var a = $0; a.append(coins[j]);return a} + getSolution(i, j - 1)
    }
```

`getSolution(amount, coins.count-1)`

Output:

`[[1, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. We define a new function `get_solution(i,j)` which means **all solution for your `table[i][j]`**.
You can think it returns an array of array, for example, the output of `get_solution(4,3)` is `[[1,1,1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,1]]`. Then:

- **Case 1.** Any solution from `get_solution(i - coins[j], j)` plus `coins[j]` is a solution for `table[i][j]`.
- **Case 2.** Any solution from `get_solution(i, j - 1)` is a solution for `table[i][j]`.

You can prove Case 1 + Case 2 is all possible solution for  `table[i][j]`(note you get `table[i][j]` by this way).

The only problem remains is to implement `get_solution(i,j)` and I think it's good for you to do it by yourself.

If you still got any question, please don't hesitate to leave a comment here.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! My resulting code is ugly, but now that I understand the solution, I'll be able to make it better. I edited the question with the function. Thank you :)